# Making a HTTPS Post request using XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, post, https, request

I'm trying to use the API from Web Of Knowledge(WoK) to obtain some data. The documentation explain that you have to do POST Requests through HTTPS, sending a XML which contains the queries. But I only get the error 400 form server. (Bad Request)

Here is my code, I found it in Google and I make some fixes for my case.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



    // Get target URL
    String strURL = /*Here the Server URL*/;

    // Get file to be posted
    String strXMLFilename = "src/main/resources/xml/wosdata.xml";
    File input = new File(strXMLFilename);

    // Prepare HTTP post
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(strURL);

    // Request content will be retrieved directly
    // from the input stream
    // Per default, the request content needs to be buffered
    // in order to determine its length.
    // Request body buffering can be avoided when
    // content length is explicitly specified
    post.setRequestEntity(new InputStreamRequestEntity(
            new FileInputStream(input), input.length()));

    // Specify content type and encoding
    // If content encoding is not explicitly specified
    // ISO-8859-1 is assumed
    post.setRequestHeader(
            "Content-type", "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");

    // Get HTTP client
    HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();



    // Execute request
    try {

        int result = httpclient.executeMethod(post);

        // Display status code
        System.out.println("Response status code: " + result);

        // Display response
        System.out.println("Response body: ");
        System.out.println(post.getResponseBodyAsString());


    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        // Release current connection to the connection pool 
        // once you are done
        post.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to add the https certificate downloaded from the target website to your cacerts file before this will work?  I think you would if you were using an HttpsURLConnection.  The HttpClient may handle this for you, but could be worth checking.

Comment: Can you switch on wire logging as per [this](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html) and see what is sent over the wire? And generally increase the log levels for httpclient.

Comment: @Mikey If he got 400 his HTTPS/SSL must be working perfectly, as the 400 comes back in an HTTP header.

Comment: I just get the solution... The official documentation was wrong, the URL was incorrect. So I change it and my original code works fine.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments and solutions. Sorry about the "simple" problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with the XML you are sending. You will have to look at server logs to find out exactly what, as 400 deliberately tells you as little as possible.

Comment: but server isn't mine... is from a web services.

Comment: Makes no difference. You are sending it something it doesn't understand. If you can't get help from the server end you need the precise specification of the input expected and you need another way to verify that it's correct. In this case an XML schema checker seems indicated.

Comment: I copied the xml as it is shown in the documentation, and make some changes to adjust the content with a query test. But I still get the 400

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this. First read the contents of the xml to String and do post using a StringRequestEntity.

```
// Get file to be posted
String strXMLFilename = "src/main/resources/xml/wosdata.xml";
StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();

try {
  BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(strXMLFilename)));
  try {
    while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){
      contents.append(line);
      contents.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
  }
  finally {
    input.close();
  }



  StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(contents.toString());
  post.setEntity(requestEntity);
```

Comment: I cannot create a StringRequestEntity using a StringBuilder. Eclipse wants to change the type of contents to String.

Comment: sorry. use StringRequestEntity requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(contents.toString())

Comment: Better use StringEntity instead of StringRequestEntity as I have edited above because the constructor of StringRequestEntity is deprecated now.

Comment: I used PostMethod post = new PostMethod(strURL);

Comment: and then, use setEntity... but Eclipse tolds me that that method isn't implemented.

Comment: use org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost instead

Comment: None of this solves the *problem*. The problem is HTTP 400 'Bad Request'.

Comment: @AciD Not by fritzing around like this with transport mechanisms instead of content. See my answer.